# Not receiving the critic badge

Tags: support, badges

The <kbd>Critic badge</kbd> states that you need to downvote 1 post "first downvote" well I downvoted 3 and still have not received it:

> all time                by type                       month              week     day
>    152    up               54 question        155     155     5
>    3  down        101 answer

:

> As you can see: 3 down 152 up!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Patience, my young Padawan. Handing out badges does not seem to be instantaneous.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Sorry!

Comment: If I recall correctly, some badges only run once a day since their determination is a bit CPU intensive. It's definitely not a real time thing.

Comment: I believe the reason in this case isn't necessarily server load, but to protect anonymity—if the badge was awarded at the exact downvote time, it would be relatively simple for users to figure out who downvoted them, which is not good for anyone.